# How to get PID of started App in C#

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have got a few  pairs of the identical apps.

It looks like

> Pair 1: App A + App B
>
> Pair 2: App A + App B
>
> and etc

Each App A starts App B from its folder. (They are both at the same folder.)

So I start it like this

**Code of App A**

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = FileManager.AppDirectoryName + "\\" + AppB;
p.Start();
```

**And I also stop App B like this.**

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{  
    if (p.ProcessName == AppB)
    {
        p.Kill();
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that at the same time could be many App B  executing so this method does not allow to detect target App B to kill.

I assume to use **PID** of App B to kill it.
But I don't know how to obtain **PID** at the moment to start App B...

Any clue?

Comment: use `Id` property. `p.Id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting the app, the Id property on the Process object will indicate the PID of the newly started process

`var PID = p.Id;`

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference to the Process object:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\notepad.exe";
p.Start();

// ...

p.Kill();
```

or remember its PID:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\notepad.exe";
p.Start();

long pid = p.Id;

// ...

Process.GetProcessById(pid).Kill();
```